# Flux through a circle in 3d space

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be the vector field $F(x,y,z)=0\,\textbf{i}+0\,\textbf{j}+2z\,\textbf{k}$.
Now calculate the flux integral $\iint_S F\cdot dS$ upwards (thus facing the positive z direction) where $S$ is the unit circle in the $(x,y)$-axis.
Am I wrong to believe that this integral is equal to 0, because $S$ is a flat circle at the origin and thus it has no flux? I'm not able to see how it shouldn't be equal to 0. Is there a way to parameterise $F$ such that this integral is solvable?

Comment: Indeed, how do you parametrize the unit disk in the $xy$-plane (a circle is a curve; the disk is the two-dimensional object it bounds)? Do that. Then try it with $F=(z+1)\mathbf k$ and see what happens.